# RSACryptoServiceProvider Fails to decrypt on server 2012 only

Tags: c#, encryption, server, windows-server-2012

I have an application which decrypts data using c# RSACryptoServiceProvider , with a private key.
This works every time on windows 7, server 2008 but as soon as it runs on server 2012 it fails with Bad Data?
I created a console app with the values, and key hard coded so I could be 100% its the same and run it on all OS versions, and still the same, works on Windows 7, and server 2008 but not on server 2012.
Its driving me crazy, does anyone have any ideas please?

Code shown below:

```
public class Decryptor
{
    private readonly RSACryptoServiceProvider provider;

    public Decryptor(int keySize)
    {
        provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySize);
    }

    public string Decrypt(string value)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Decoding from base64");
            var fromBase64 = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
            Console.WriteLine("Decoded ok from base64");
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypting....");
            var decrypted = provider.Decrypt(fromBase64, false);
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypted ok");
            Console.WriteLine("Encoding to UTF8....");
            var utf8Encoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);
            Console.WriteLine("Encoded to UTF8 ok");

            return utf8Encoded;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {   
            Console.WriteLine("Error in Decrypt:" + ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Inner Exception:" + ex.InnerException);
            Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace:" + ex.StackTrace);
        }

        return "Error";
    }

    public void LoadPrivateKey(string privateKey)
    {
        try
        {
            provider.FromXmlString(privateKey);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in LoadPrivateKey:" + ex.Message); 
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: You should give more details about the error if possible, not just "Bad Data".

Comment: I would at your place at least also take time to examine some other RSA software that are freely available on the Internet and see whether they are good/secure and maybe eventually more satisfying for your particular needs. (A by nature clearly biased view of mine: If what you need is encryption of common personal communications, I suggest that you also take a look at a software of mine: s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/7234475/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'm trying to stick with the .net assemblies, and "Bad data" is the only meaning full part of the error that's generated. Not much to go on but the exception only tells me that's its the RSACryptoServiceProvider that has failed nothing else.